# Nothing happens when building and running image with docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new at docker and I want to make an image of my node.js api and webapp.
I'm on Windows.
I tried following in my Dockerfile and then execute these commands but nothing happens.
Container runs well but I can't reached my webapp on localhost:8080

docker run -d -p 8080:8080 web3-webapp-image

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Can you try: docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 web3-webapp-image? also if you do docker logs on the container, what does it say?

Comment: localhost:8080 is still not working and when I try to launch my api-image it does'nt create a container with these cmd docker run -d web3api-docker-image

Comment: any output of the command? what happens if you docker ps ?

Comment: Output of my command is something like this 1513859c921853cc86a6b25bbdb8af1e24f7e8868328a5495193621dc6d41ff8 and when I do docker ps I have one container for my webapp and none for my node.js api. And I still not access my webapp with localhost

Comment: the best way to debug is to run in forground `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 web3-webapp-image`, btw is the node app really litening on port `8080`

Comment: Can you just do docker logs on the container to find out what the node app is saying? because your node app also has to be listening on the same port that's being exposed

Answer (score 0):

Your node application must also be listening to the same port that is being exposed.

If your app is listening to port 3000 and you're publishing port 8080, then your app isn't going to be able to open up communication back to your localhost.

You can fix this by either publishing the same port the node app is listening on, or change the port your node app is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's problem is solved. App was listening on port 3000 et I was not publishing on the same port.